# Approximating smooth functions with polynomials subject to constraints.

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Suppose that we are given a smooth function $h:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $h \circ F= h \circ G$ for two *polynomial* functions $F,G:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. each component of $F$ and $G$ is a real polynomial of $m$-variables). Can we approximate $h$ arbitrarily well by polynomial functions $P_h$ which also satisfy $P_h \circ F= P_h \circ G$ (or at least such that these functions are "close")? How about when $F$ and $G$ are not polynomial but smooth?

Comment: In what norm are you approximating?

Comment: @Yemon: I want to leave that vague for now. If this can be done in *some* norm I am interested.

Comment: @David: since your domain is non-compact, is $h$ supposed to be bounded? If not, then you will need to have a weight in the norm, which makes life tricky. For instance, what are you hoping for in the case $m=n=1$?

Comment: @Yemon: Sadly, I have to let $h$ be an arbitrary smooth function, so I cannot assume it's bounded.

Comment: @Yemon: For me though, it's ok not to even have a norm. I just need a reasonably functorial topology on the space of smooth functions for which I can find a convergent sequence of polynomials satisfying the properties I listed.

Comment: The condition $h \circ F = h \circ G$ is a functional equation, which may have no nonconstant polynomial solutions.  For example, consider $n=m=1$, $F(x) = x$, $G(x) = x+1$, where the functional equation says $h$ is periodic with period 1. 

Comment: @Robert: Good point. So I suppose it is unreasonable to demand that these polynomials literally satisfy the equation. Instead (as I remarked in parentheses) one can ask can we approximate $h$ by polynomials such that $h \circ F$ and $h \circ G$ are "close".

Comment: For "close" you need a topology. The only topology that makes sense here is the $x$-adic topology, I think. (So $x^n$ divides $h\circ F-h\circ G$ for some large $n$) Do you agree?

Also, do you want to approximate near a point?

Comment: Thank you to everyone who has helped me think about this. It appears that I need something much stronger than what I have said for my purposes, and you have made me realize this.

Answer (score 2):

In general not. For $m=n=1$, $F$ and $G$ must be of equal degree (otherwise $P_h\circ F$ anf $P_g\circ F$ are of different degree). But even equal degrees don't guarantee anything: if $F(x)=x$, $G(x) = x+1$, then no polynomial $P$ can fulfill $P\circ F=P\circ G$ (no polynomial is periodic).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets.  By Stone-Weierstrass, any continuous function $h$ can be approximated by a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ in this topology, and then $P_n \circ F - P_n \circ G$ approximates $h \circ F - h \circ G = 0$ in this topology  (because if $K \subset {\mathbb R}^m$ is compact, $F(K) \cup G(K)$ is compact).

Comment: The statement "if $P_n$ approximates $h$, then $P_n \circ F-P_n \circ G$ approaches $0$" is true whenever composition and subtraction are continuous maps in whatever topology on smooth functions you're considering. Since most (all?) reasonable topologies will satisfy that property, in general this will not give an extra constraint.

